# Proper way to destroy linked List?

Tags: c, arrays, list

How do I destroy my linked list completely? For instance, right when I create my linked list and call the print list function, nothing happens obviously since nothing is in the list. When I add nodes to the list, it prints them out fine. But when I destroy my list and try to print the list I expect nothing to print out again, but im seg faulting. *The head of my linked list is a dummy node too

```
void destroyList(listNode *List)
{
    listNode *temp = malloc(sizeof(listNode));
    temp = List->next;
    while (List != NULL)
    {
        temp = List;
        List = List->next;
        free(temp);             
    }
}

void printList(listNode * List)
{
    List = List->next;

    while (List != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n",List->val);        
        List = List->next;     
    }  
}
```

Comment: Why would you allocate a listNode when you're trying to destroy one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're segfaulting because you're still trying to climb down the chain of `free`'d pointers which you can't do. Just set the first `->next` to `NULL` and you're good to go.

```
void destroyList(listNode *List)
{
    listNode *temp; // removed malloc, it's not necessary.
    listNode *originalHead = List;
    temp = List->next;
    while (List != NULL)
    {
        temp = List;
        List = List->next;
        free(temp);             
    }

    originalHead->next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: After comment from  ckruczek i am adding this as a comment. You are also deleting your dummy pointer at the behinning of the list. Is that what you want? Maybe your print method is supposed to show always the dummy and when you try to print a list without dummy you get a segfault. You must decide on your constraints for list at first.

Answer (score 1):

After you call destroyList, you will want the List pointer to be set to NULL.  Because it is pass be value, you have to pass the address of the List pointer into destroyList. So, I would do it like this:

```
void destroyList(listNode **List) {
  listNode *temp1, *temp2;
  if (!List) {
    return;
  }
  temp1 = *List;
  while (temp1) {
    temp2 = temp1->next;
    free(temp1);
    temp1 = temp2 
  }
  free(*List);
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
listNode *foo;

// some code

destroyList(&foo);
```